# Javascript - Debugging window.print()

Tags: javascript

I am being forced to abuse HTML.   I am creating an html webpage that is actually a form meant for print output.  In other words, this should be a PDF.  It isn't.  It won't be cause the 3rd party stuff costs too much and at this point I do not have time to convert it all.

It is all HTML and I print it via js "window.print()".  In the latest FF The print comes out one way.  In IE 7 another.  Both are wrong.

I don't seem to have any way to perform a print-preview so I am burning through trees like a forest fire.  Does anyone have any tips for troubleshooting the print functionality?  I mean, I may have to start exploring the damn postscript or something.  I'm clueless.

Comment: `print` is pretty much un-troubleshootable. Firefox has a good print preview though that might save a tree or two :) Maybe describe what the problems are exactly - somebody may be able to come up with something. Also, if it's a form that is there only for printing, have you considered using PDF forms?

Comment: [CSS PRINT MEDIA!](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: @Pekka - There's 3 pages.  The first looks good.  The second, basically the logo, table header, and anything that repeats is stripped out.  The third doesnt display at all >.<.   Epic failure.

Comment: Brian are you working with absolute positioning and/or tables that span across pages?

Comment: @Pekka - I setup the core layout with div's.  They are sized with fixed width and height using "em" units.  There is a table too.  Neither the table or the divs come out looking correct.  I'm currently giving Apache's XSL-FO processor a shot.  Because I already have this setup as an XSLT to html.  Hopefully I can get an XSL-FO setup quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get yourself a virtual PDF printer plugin.

MacOS X has this built in.  I'm sure I've seen similar for Windows systems.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  Hopefully this product can convert HTML otherwise its not going to work.  Boss wants this all done yesterday.

Comment: The PDF output looks very close to IE7 if not the same.  Saves me some physical prints for sure.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into free [Print to PDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp) solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Alexey has a good option... also you can try Primo PDF (Windows) that allows you to print directly to a PDF document... this will save trees